# passport.js facebook authentication next not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js

The passport.js strategy that I am trying to implement is the one for the facebook provider. I have tested with the text book example (from https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example) and it seems the redirect is never called.

The redirect sequence works fine except when the user is logged in, it redirects to the homepage, even when explicitly putting a different URL in the callback.

So everything works except the last redirect, which should end up at https://xx.com/testing which never happens.

nodejs 6, express 4+, passport 3.2

What is going wrong?

**Strategy**

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: xx,
  clientSecret: 'xx',
  callbackURL: 'https://xx.com/auth/facebook/callback/',
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'name', 'displayName']
},
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile)
  }
))
```

**Route**

```
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['public_profile', 'email']}))
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // never gets called
    console.log('I don't get called!!!')
    res.redirect('/testing')
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

`/testing` goes to `successRedirect`

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
    successRedirect: '/testing',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

UPDATE: Use `passport.authorize`

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authorize('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
       res.redirect('/testing')
    });
```

Comment: That works as expected, but I would like to execute some code, then redirect.